# In Lua Random number generation issue

Tags: lua

We are performing task as Accept a number as the seed value for `math.randomseed()`, and generate a random integer (interval [1,6]) using `math.random()` during each iteration of a loop, and continue the loop till the number is 6.

For which we had written code as

```
i = io.read()
local count = 0
math.randomseed(i)
for x = 1, 4 do
    value = math.random(1, 6)
    print(value)
    count = count + 1 
end
print(count)
```

We failed to pass test because

```
    Input (stdin)
    Run as Custom Input
    0

    Your Output (stdout)
     3
     5
     5
     6
     2

    Expected Output
    3
    5
    5
    6
    4
```

Please help us

Comment: you are supposed to run the loop until the random value equals six. so stop changing your  for loop limit every 2 minutes. would you please read the Lua manual?  if you have to repeat somethinig until some condition is true, why not give a repeat until statement a chance?

Comment: this is final code which we written, still not working as issue now...

Comment: i = io.read()
local count = 0
local a = 6
math.randomseed(i)
for x = 1, 4 do
    value = math.random(1, 6)
    repeat
    print(value)
    until value < a
    count = count + 1 
end
print(count)

Comment: and check the task. why is the expected output 3 5 5 6 4 if you are supposed to run it until the number is 6. the expected output should be 3 5 5 6 then. but regardless of that your code is still not correct

Comment: thanks we got your point but nearly not getting is value is 6 then  how we should exit

Comment: I really doubt your example.  I ran the code myself and got 4 as the last number instead of 2.  That only makes sense since it is the count and you appear to add 1 to count each time you print a random number and you print 4 random numbers.  Where is the 2 coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP code seems to be having loop problems. I encourage the OP to read the Lua documentation about [Control Structures](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.3.4), where Lua's `while`, `repeat until`, and `goto` are described, as well as the following manual section about Lua's [For Statement](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.3.5). It is difficult to write any program in any language without understanding the fundamental control structures of the language.

OP problem can be solved in a variety of ways.

### Using `for`

```
-- for version
i = io.read()
math.randomseed(i)

local count
for i = 1, math.huge do
  local value = math.random(1, 6)
  print(value)
  count = i
  if value == 6 then break end
end
print(count)
```

Here `math.huge` is the largest representable number in Lua, typically the special value `inf`, making this effectively an infinite loop. The variable `i` keeps track of how many random numbers have been generated, but since `i` will not be visible outside of the loop, the `count` variable is needed to copy the value of `i` so that it can be printed at the end.

### Using `while`

```
-- while version
i = io.read()
math.randomseed(i)

local value = math.random(1, 6)
local count = 1
while value < 6 do
  print(value)
  count = count + 1
  value = math.random(1, 6)
end
print(value)
print(count)
```

Here the looping construct *begins* with a test, so a test value must be created before the loop begins. This means that the `count` must be initialized to 1 before the loop begins, and it also means that the call to `math.random` will be duplicated. Not pretty.

### Using `repeat until`

```
-- repeat until version
i = io.read()
math.randomseed(i)

local count = 0
repeat
  local value = math.random(1, 6)
  print(value)
  count = count + 1
until value == 6
print(count)
```

Here the test comes at the *end* of the loop construct. This allows the code to call `math.random` only once.

### Using `goto`

```
-- goto version
i = io.read()
math.randomseed(i)

local count = 0
::loop::
local value = math.random(1, 6)
print(value)
count = count + 1
if value < 6 then goto loop end
print(count)
```

You probably should not use `goto` to solve this problem, but you can. You have to be careful with `goto` in Lua; you can't jump into a block, out of a function, or into the scope of a local variable.

As you can see, there are some subtleties to these looping constructs, and using them requires some familiarity with the details.

All four versions produce identical outputs for the same inputs:

```
$ lua loops.lua
42
2
5
3
2
2
4
6
7
```